# How to create a remote copy (not local clone) of a VSTS GIT repository

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a VSTS GIT repository, I want to create new remote repository which would be the copy of existing repository. How to do it ? Please note I am not looking for GIT clone to clone a local copy of remote repository.

Atul

Comment: You could clone the repo and then remove the git folder

Comment: So there is no in built command to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options:

- Clone the repo with `git clone --depth=1` (which only clones the most recent commit), then add a new remote and push.
- If you're staying within your VSTS account, you can *[fork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/concepts/forks)* the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no in built command, create a local clone remove the git folder, create empty repo & copy the folder & push.